# Chamada ao sistema dup2 vs. write&read

Tags: c, linux

Estou com uma dúvida em perceber porque é que em alguns casos existem exemplos de conversas em o processo pai e o processo filho - obtido através da chamada ao sistema fork ( ) - que usam as funções read e write e noutros casos usam o dup2.Eu estou a tentar criar uma função que me permite ao filho ler do pai e depois passar para maiúsculas aquilo que leu do pai e escrever isso para o pai ler. Eu tenho a seguinte função para já

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Declaração pid
    int pid;

    //Declaração das duas variáveis que irei servir de pipe
    int fd1[2],fd2[2];

    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);

    pid = fork();

    //Verificação de erro na criação do processo filho
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        perror("Fork:");
    }

    else
    {
        //Caso estejamos no processo filho
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            close(fd1[1]); //Quando o filho estiver a ler a mensagem do pai o lado de escrita (posição 1) é fechado
            dup2(fd1[0],0); //A executar a leitura

            close(fd2[0]); //Depois o pai irá fechar o lado de leitura (posição 0) para escrever para o pai
            dup2(fd2[1],1); //A executar a escrita


        }

        //Caso estejamos no processo pai
        else
        {
            //O pai fecha no seu código os descritores que o filho utilizei no dup2
            close(fd1[0]);
            close(fd2[1]);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Não pretendo a resolução do problema porque sei que a finalidade da plataforma não é essa mas sim antes alguém que me explique se estou a proceder de forma correta ou se estou a errar.

Enunciado do problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O pipe() parece estar sendo usado corretamente no código.

O objetivo do dup2() é duplicar o file descriptor para um número definido. No caso do código, o processo-filho está colocando um pipe no lugar do file descriptor 0 que é o "stdin", e outro pipe no lugar do "stdout". Isto normalmente só se faz quando o processo-filho vai chamar exec() em seguida, para que o novo executável "herde" os pipes como stdin e stdout. Se o processo-filho vai continuar rodando sem chamar exec(), poderia usar os fd's do pipe mesmo para comunicar-se com o processo-pai.

Comment: Segundo percebi neste caso em concreto não há necessidade de utilizar o dup2. Basta usar as funções write e read para executar a troca de informação entre o pai e o filho. Sendo que o pai escreve na pipe onde o filho lê e o filho irá escrever na outra pipe para depois o pai ler.

Comment: Por isso sim a resposta acaba por ser correta porque não está a ser executado nenhum exec ( ).